# GPG command: --list-sigs only from Trusted keys?

Tags: command-line, gpg

Whenever I use `gpg --list-sigs` command I risk getting tons of "spam" from sigs of people I do not know.

Is there a command in GPG where I can `--list-sigs` but only sigs from keys that I have marked as having a Trust level? What is this command?

Answer (score 4):

`gpg --list-keys --list-options show-uid-validity`

This will show a validity calculation next to each address (unknown, undef, marginal, full, ultimate). You can then grep -v the unknown and undef ones, this leaves the ones you (or your web of trust) have some trust for.

`gpg --list-keys --list-options show-uid-validity | grep -v "unknown\|undef"`

For list-sigs the listing is slightly different, so this may work instead:

`gpg --list-sigs |grep -v "User ID not found" |grep -v "sig  "`

note two spaces on the last "sig  ".

This will weed out the unknown user IDs and omit any signatures that don't have a trust level. For the meaning of the number right next to "sig", do `man gpg` and search for --ask-cert-level.

You may also want to look into `--list-options no-show-unusable-uids`, but in my test it didn't make a significant difference.

Comment: how do I make this work with the --list-sigs command?

Comment: w/ some keys, I get rows of expired keys and [User ID not found]. I want to just see my sig and those from other keys I trust instead of having to wade through expired keys and not found user ids.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the --list-sigs part. I'll update the answer.